# Ubuntu 19.04 Deskotop in black no icons issue

Tags: 19.04

Today I started a session, as every day in ubuntu, no icon appeared on the login screen and I did not take it with importance, it starts as I normally do and when I opened my session the desktop was completely black, no icon was visible, in the taskbar either, I can open chrome, firefox, visual studio code, all without problems but at the moment I try to open the guake terminal the session closes automatically along with all the programs I had open, it also does not detect the audio nor It allows me to open the default terminal.

I tried with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt install --uninstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and everything stays the same, and I tried the same with

> nomodeset

in the grub